# Setting up Ubuntu Linux 16.04 as a router within a VM

Tags: linux, router, iptables, nat

*(Migrated from https://serverfault.com/questions/895250/setting-up-ubuntu-linux-16-04-as-a-router-within-a-vm)*

I want to setup an Ubuntu VM as a router running [atcd](https://github.com/facebook/augmented-traffic-control) so I can do targetted testing of a single device under a variety of network conditions. I've gotten parts working but am stuck with getting the gateway to route my packets.

Gist of what I've tried:

- Create an Ubuntu 16.04 VM (`"router"`) on an Ubuntu 16.04 host (`"laptop"`)
- Created two NICs for the VM, both bridged to the host's single WiFi adapter
- Set the first NIC (`enp0s3`) to be statically configured to be the gateway, at 192.168.0.199
- Set the second NIC (`enp0s8`) to be auto-configured over DHCP, at say 192.168.0.100
- Used the following `iptables` rules (from [here](http://www.alenazi.me/install-ubuntu-as-a-router-using-vritualbox/) and [here](https://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html)) on `router`:

  `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s8 -j MASQUERADE
  iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s8 -j ACCEPT`
- Device/host under test (`"test-device"`) configured to be at static IP 192.168.0.77, configured to use 192.168.0.199 as the gateway.

At this point, I'm able to reach an HTTP server running on `router` via both 192.168.0.199 as well as 192.168.0.100 from other machines on the LAN that are configured to still use the Wifi router as the gateway (192.168.0.1).

`test-device` is able to ping hosts on the Internet, however, it is unable to setup TCP connections to them (for instance `curl www.google.com` fails with "Destination unreachable".

Some other things worth sharing:

### `iptables` configuration on `router`:

```
root# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 12012 packets, 5058K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  enp0s8 enp0s3  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  enp0s3 enp0s8  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3220 packets, 271K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

### `ip route` entries

```
root# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s3 onlink 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.199 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.121
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do next and could use some help!

Answer (score -1):

You *haven't activated the IP forwarding* in sysctl...

To **perform IP routing** in Ubuntu Linux:

```
sudo nano sysctl.conf

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the similar to your user name, it appears that you might have linked to your own site. If you do link to a site you are affiliated with, you *must disclose that affiliation*. If you don't disclose your affiliation, it's considered spam.  See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [How to not be a spammer](//superuser.com/help/promotion).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing out the link. In addition to the self promotion rule - it might be useful to say how the link would be useful, rather than going "there's more stuff there"

Comment: @Makyen: thx - please do not consider as spam / will read it through and return to you